# Integrating ActiveMQ and Wildfly with Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, wildfly-8

I'm trying to make Wildfly and ActiveMQ working together with Apache Camel, let me explain the scenario. Every hour a camel batch poll an FTP server, grab the files and send them to an ActiveMQ broker. The broker implements two routes, `numbers` and `big.numbers`. Messages are queued into `numbers`, if they are not ready to be send they are routed to `big.numbers`. Messages in `big.numbers` are dequeued and translated by camel processor and queued to `numbers` as ready to be send. The ready to be send messages in `numbers` are sent to Wildfly where a MDB do something.
Everything works fine except for the last step. When MDB receive a message throws an Exception: `org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQBytesMessage cannot be cast to javax.jms.TextMessage`.
Here is the `camel.xml` I use to implement routes on my ActiveMQ broker:

```
...
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <package>edu.foo.amq.camel</package>
    <dataFormats>
        <string id="utf-8-string" charset="UTF-8"/>
    </dataFormats>


    <route id="toBigNumeri">
        <from uri="activemq:numbers.queue"/>
        <marshal ref="utf-8-string"/>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>
                    ${in.header.readyToGo} != true
                </simple>
                <process ref="big.numbers.processor"/>
                <to uri="activemq:big.numbers.queue"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <process ref="done.processor"/>
                <to uri="wildflycf:generatoreQueue?username=dummyusr&amp;password=dummy1234"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>           
    </route>

    <route id="toNumeri">
        <from uri="activemq:big.numbers.queue"/>
        <marshal ref="utf-8-string"/>
        <split>
            <tokenize token="\n"/>
            <process ref="numbers.processor"/>
            <setHeader headerName="readyToGo">
                <constant>true</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="activemq:numbers.queue"/>
        </split>
        <process ref="dump.processor"/>
        <to uri="activemq:dump.queue"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
      <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
        <property name="userName" value="${activemq.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${activemq.password}"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jndiTmp" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">http-remoting://localhost:8080</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">jhon</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">doe</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="wfcf" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTmp"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="wildflycf" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="wfcf"/>
</bean>
...
```

Here is my MDB:

```
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@MessageDriven(name="GeneratoreMDB", activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"), 
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationLookup", propertyValue=QueueHandler.jmsQueue)}
)
public class QueueHandler implements MessageListener {

public static final String jmsQueue = "/export/jms/generatoreQueue";

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(QueueHandler.class);

  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
    try {
        log.info(((TextMessage) arg0).getText());
        ...
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the exception my MDB throws:

```
2014-12-05 09:12:04,864 ERROR [org.hornetq.ra] (Thread-35 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1727074612)) HQ154004: Failed to deliver message: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQBytesMessage cannot be cast to javax.jms.TextMessage
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:163)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:253)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:342)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.messagedriven.MessageDrivenComponentDescription$5$1.processInvocation(MessageDrivenComponentDescription.java:211)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
at edu.foo.incassionline.generatore.jms.QueueHandler$$$view3.onMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:139)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:73)
at edu.foo.incassionline.generatore.jms.QueueHandler$$$endpoint1.onMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.onMessage(HornetQMessageHandler.java:319) [hornetq-ra-2.4.1.Final.jar:]
at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1116) [hornetq-core-client-2.4.1.Final.jar:]
at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$500(ClientConsumerImpl.java:56) [hornetq-core-client-2.4.1.Final.jar:]
at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1251) [hornetq-core-client-2.4.1.Final.jar:]
at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:104) [hornetq-core-client-2.4.1.Final.jar:]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQBytesMessage cannot be cast to javax.jms.TextMessage
at edu.foo.incassionline.generatore.jms.QueueHandler.onMessage(QueueHandler.java:27)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:251)
... 49 more
```

I can't get why the MDB gets the message as HornetQ message and not a simple JMS Message.

Comment: From the stacktrace it indicates you send the message to the queue as a bytes message. And on the other side you try to type cast that as a text message. You need to use the same message type with JMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending a JMS message, Camel converts the message body to the following JMS message types (see [here](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html)):

```
╔══════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ Body Type            ║ JMS Message             ║
╠══════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ String               ║ javax.jms.TextMessage   ║
║ org.w3c.dom.Node     ║ javax.jms.TextMessage   ║
║ Map                  ║ javax.jms.MapMessage    ║
║ java.io.Serializable ║ javax.jms.ObjectMessage ║
║ byte[]               ║ javax.jms.BytesMessage  ║
║ java.io.File         ║ javax.jms.BytesMessage  ║
║ java.io.Reader       ║ javax.jms.BytesMessage  ║
║ java.io.InputStream  ║ javax.jms.BytesMessage  ║
║ java.nio.ByteBuffer  ║ javax.jms.BytesMessage  ║
╚══════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Please, check the type of the message body in `big.numbers.processor`. There are two possibilities: 1) create a "text message type body" according Camel's convertion rules and cast to `TextMessage`, or 2) cast to `BytesMessage` instead.

Comment: Right! I change my route 
`<to uri="wildflycf:generatoreQueue?username=dummyusr&amp;password=dummy1234"/>`
like this:
`<to uri="wildflycf:generatoreQueue?username=dummyusr&amp;password=dummy1234&amp;jmsTextMessage=true"/>`
and now my MDB can handle messages.